# Gatsby.js Conditional querying

Tags: gatsby

I want to use conditional query in my component like this:

```
export const pageQuery =
  DATA_SOURCE === 'strapi'
    ? graphql`
        query AllNews {
          allStrapiApiupdates(sort: { order: DESC, fields: [date] }) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                title
                description
                date(formatString: "DD.MM", locale: "ru")
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `
    : graphql`
        query AllNews {
          allMarkdownRemark(
            sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }
            filter: { frontmatter: { type: { eq: "news" } } }
          ) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                frontmatter {
                  title
                  date(formatString: "DD.MM", locale: "ru")
                  type
                }
                html
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `
```

But I got error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: graphql is not defined
        at Module.eval (D:/Projects/AHML-DWH/api-news-front/src/pages/index.tsx:68)
        at eval (D:/Projects/AHML-DWH/api-news-front/src/pages/index.tsx:146)
        at Module../src/pages/index.tsx (commons.js:9487)
 ...
```

This is related with transpiling, I suppose. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is, no, this is not possible.

Gatsby pulls the queries out of your template files and treats the specially. It doesn't have any way to make those queries dynamic. In theory, you could achieve this with a [GraphQL directive](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#directives). But I don't think it's possible to do this inside Gatsby in the way you've posted.

Answer (score 2):

From what I'm trying now, I'll tell you that you cannot use directives `@include(if:$myBolean)` with *filters*, *sorts*, etc, but you can use them **in gatsby as well** with fields.

Then, in your case, you could execute the whole query with the directive, like

```
       query AllNews($myBolean: Boolean!) {
          allMarkdownRemark(
            sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }
            filter: { frontmatter: { type: { eq: "news" } } }
          ) @include(if:$myBoolean) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                frontmatter {
                  title
                  date(formatString: "DD.MM", locale: "ru")
                  type
                }
                html
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

and then you can add the two queries in one graphql call, and execute only one of them depending on the boolean